# Update existing column data MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have a table with `speed` column in MySQL DB.

speed

```
100 Mbits
120 Mbits
```

I am trying to update this column to remove `Mbits` part from this column.

Can I have an in place query which can do this task?

I tried googling which suggested `split_str` function which looks complicated for this task.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Madan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Update table set speed=LEFT(speed, INSTR(speed, ' ') - 1)
```

Result would be from:

```
100 Mbits
120 Mbits
```

To

```
100
120
```

Comment: or, `speed = REPLACE(speed,' Mbits','')`

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace` to do this.

```
update mytable set speed = replace(speed, 'Mbits', '')
where lower(speed) like '%mbits%'
```

Edit: Multiplying by 1000 where speed contains `Mbits`

```
update mytable set speed = 1000 * cast(replace(speed, 'Mbits', '') as signed)
where lower(speed) like '%mbits%'
```

Comment: And optionally add WHERE speed LIKE '%Mbits%'. (If only some of the rows have Mbits.) To reduce transaction size.

Comment: sure @jarlh.. i added the filter

Comment: @jarlh Most likely it has no index on the `mbits` value, so adding the filter means a full table scan anyway, plus searching in the text using `LIKE` which I don't think is more efficient than the `replace`. So it is likely that adding the filter will reduce the speed. ;-)

Comment: @RacilHilan, the whole table will be read anyway, with or without the where clause. LIKE is maybe a bit slower than replace, but if only a small part of the rows will be edited, the size of the write set will be significantly smaller. (Perhaps MySQL does things differently here???)

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I've already said that the whole table will be read in both ways, so we agree on that. I also agree with you that if it is only a few records will be edited, then adding the condition is the way to go for the reason you mentioned. However, my feeling from the OP's question is that all the records have the text to be removed, so adding the condition in such a case means that the `LIKE` and `replace` will be doing the same job twice which is slower. We don't know which case is the one the OP has, so I will +1 your comments for possible usefulness.

Comment: @vkp  ,I want to multiple the same field after removing Mbits by 1000 wherever only Mbits is present,Is it possible here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use substring_index. something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET speed = SUBSTRING_INDEX(speed,'Mbits', 1);
WHERE speed LIKE '%Mbits%'
```